# Finding python modules in rqt plugins?

Tags: rospy, catkin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have defined Python modules in setup.py for a package and these modules are found when running Python programs from another package using rosrun. But running

```
rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -s lrs_rqt/rqt_quad.quad.Quad
```

where I in quad.py have:

```
from quad.qcon import *
```

then it does not work. It does not find the qcon. So does it work differently with plugins? And if so how does it work?

I am using groovy and catkin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58260/finding-python-modules-in-rqt-plugins?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a Python mistake. The file I did

```
from quad.qcon import *
```

in was called quad.py and that seems not to be a good idea. I renamed it and everything is working as expected.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0